# BufferedWriter creates empty file with nothing inside

Tags: java, hadoop, outputstream, bufferedwriter

I have the following code:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());    
Path filePath2 = Path.mergePaths(outputPath, new Path( "/SomeFile"));
            BufferedWriter writer2 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(filePath2,true)));
            writer2.write("Key: " + key.toString() + "\nValue: " + values.iterator().next().getSensCol().toString());

            writer2.close();
```

I'm using the Hadoop library for some of these classes. After I execute it, I see the file is created but there is nothing inside it, any ideas why that might be?

Comment: flush is not required because close will cause flush internally.

Comment: What is in variable `fs`?

Comment: FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(context.getConfiguration());

Comment: There is only `java.nio.file.FileSystem` in the standard API and it does not have a `get` method ...

Comment: are you using hadoop library?

Comment: Yes I'm using org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path and org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

Comment: The code is incomplete. Post a minimal working sample. Otherwise I'd just guess that `key` is `null` and you swallow the NPE.

Comment: Why do you use mixed api, java standard and hadoop api? i think you should use only hadoop api.. please, follow [this](https://tutorials.techmytalk.com/2014/08/16/hadoop-hdfs-java-api/) tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

There is not sufficient information for a proper diagnosis, but your code looks correct ... except (maybe) for the path.  On a Linux system (at least) a normal user should not be able write a file into the "/" directory.

So, I can suggest a couple of possible explanations:

1. The file is being written, but not to the directory that you are looking at.
2. The file open is failing (or the writes are failing) but your application is *squashing* the exception ... in some code that you haven't shown us.

---

Ah!   It looks like you are using `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` !  (The `java.nio.file` version of the `FileSystem` class doesn't have a `get` method.)

I don't think this changes my answer, apart for the stuff about being able to write to the "/" directory.  That could be permissible for a Hadoop FS.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `FileWriter` together with the `BufferedWriter`.

```java
Path filePath2 = Path.mergePaths(outputPath, new Path( "/SomeFile"));

FileWriter fileWriter2 = null;
BufferedWriter writer2 = null;

try {
    fileWriter2 = new FileWriter( filePath2.toFile() );
    writer2 = new BufferedWriter( writer2 );

    writer2.write("Key: " + key.toString() );

    //if you are going to use an Iterator, you better actually use it.
    for ( Iterator iterator = col.iterator() ; iterator.hasNext() ; ) {
        writer2.write( "\nValue: " + iterator.next()
            .getSensCol().toString() );
    }

}
catch ( IOException ex ) {
    //Exception handling
}
finally {
    writer2.close();
    fileWriter2.close();
}
```

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)